# Get Next and Previous for every element in list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
day_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to write a function which will take any number (`no`) from this list and return the next and previous element.

So, for example, if I pass **2**, I should get `[1,3]` (*1 being the previous and 3 the next elements*).

But there is a catch:

*If `no = 1` the previous element should be 6 and similarly for `no = 6` next should be 1*

I would like something like:

```
def getPrevNext(no):
    ....
    ....
    return [prev,next]

result = getPrevNext(2)  # result should be [1,3]
result2 = getPrevNext(5)  # result2 should be [4,5]
result3 = getPrevNext(1)  # result3 should be [6,2]
result4 = getPrevNext(6)  # result3 should be [5,1]
```

I tried:

```
def dummy(no):
        if no == 1:
            prev_no = 6
            next_no = 2
        elif no == 6:
            prev_no = 5
            next_no = 1
        else:
            prev_no = no - 1
            next_no = no + 1
        return [prev_no,next_no]
```

But this seems like a very naive and basic approach.. Is there a better way to do this?

FYI **List of days not required, that was just for understanding the total no.**

Comment: Why is 6 the next for 6?

Comment: You never accessed `day_list` in `dummy()`.

Comment: @timgeb it is a typo , because in code next item after 6 is 1.

Comment: @timgeb the next for 6 is 1

Comment: You should create a round list data structure.

Comment: Does the output _really_ need to be a list? IMHO, a tuple would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @PM2Ring My initial answer involuntarily returned the result in a tuple. Changed it later after someone pointed it out. Honestly though, I'd agree a tuple result is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[@juanpa.arrivillaga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074653/4909087) covers the specifics of this question quite well (which is a question on how to use modulo arithmetic).  However, in the general case of accessing the previous and next elements of *any* list, this is how I'd do it -

```
def getPrevNext(l, no):
    i = l.index(no)
    return [l[i - 1], l[(i + 1) % len(l)]]
```

```
days = list(range(1, 7))

getPrevNext(days, 2)
[1, 3]

getPrevNext(days, 1)
[6, 2]

getPrevNext(days, 6)
[5, 1]
```

The first expression `l[i - 1]` takes advantage python's ability to access elements using negative indices. The second expression, `l[(i + 1) % len(l)]`, is a common circular list access idiom.

To return a tuple instead of a list, drop the enclosing square brackets in the `return` statement -

```
def getPrevNextAsTuple(l, no):
    i = l.index(no)
    return l[i - 1], l[(i + 1) % len(l)]
```

---

Note that this does not handle the possibility of `no` not being in the list. In that case, you'd use something like exception handling to catch any `ValueError`s raised -

```
def getPrevNext(l, no):
    try:
        i = l.index(no)
    except ValueError:
        return None

    return l[i - 1], l[(i + 1) % len(l)]
```

Comment: you mean `len(l)` on the `return` line.

Comment: And you are returning a tuple. Sorry for the nitpicking, it is meant in a good way. I am actually a fan :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are working with "days" encoded 1-6, use the following:

```
>>> def prev_next_day(day):
...     day -= 1
...     prev = ((day - 1) % 6) + 1
...     next_ = ((day + 1) % 6) + 1
...     return [prev, next_]
...
>>> prev_next_day(2)
[1, 3]
>>> prev_next_day(5)
[4, 6]
>>> prev_next_day(1)
[6, 2]
>>> prev_next_day(6)
[5, 1]
```

Comment: Finding `prev` doesn't need a %6, because of negative access.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no slicing going on... original problem description was misleading, this is a problem about previous and next *days* encoded 1-6, not of a general list.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, the min day = 1 and max =6, it will not be a general list, you can remove the list parameter from your function

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nah, there's no list. Essentially the question is how to do modular arithmetic...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, I see. Somewhat misunderstood the question initially. Your answer covers this specific problem quite well. I guess you could say my answer addresses the general question of accessing the previous and next element from an arbitrary list.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ well, the title is highly misleading. [Classic XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, it's an XY problem, but hopefully the various answers here that show how to do this with a general list (that doesn't contain repeated items) will help some future readers.

Comment: @PM2Ring heh, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `slicing` (and optionally, for elegance, *mod*) like so:

```
day_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def get_prev_next(my_list, no):
  try:
    pointer = my_list.index(no)
  except ValueError:
    return []
  else:
    return [my_list[pointer-1], my_list[(pointer+1) % len(my_list)]]
```

---

**Examples:**

```
# first element
print(get_prev_next(day_list, 1))   # -> [6, 2]

# last element
print(get_prev_next(day_list, 6))   # -> [5, 1]

# any other
print(get_prev_next(day_list, 3))   # -> [2, 4]

# non-existent element
print(get_prev_next(day_list, 98))  # -> []
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say the following works:

```
def getPrevNext(no):
    day_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    return([day_list[(no-2) % 6], day_list[(no) % 6]])
```

Depending on whether or not you also only accept `1 <= no <= 6`, you could add a condition to this function like so:

```
def getPrevNext(no):
    day_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    return([day_list[(no-2) % 6], day_list[(no) % 6]] if 1 <= no <= 6 else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def getem(lst,element):
index=lst.index(element)
try:
    if index!=0 and index!=(len(lst)-1):
        return [lst[index-1],lst[index+1]]
    else:
        if index==0:
            return [lst[len(lst)-1],lst[index+1]]
        else:
            return [lst[index-1],lst[0]]
except Exception as e:
print("element does not exists")
```

try this function or you can use circular linked-list in this function i have mimicked that behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a list of days?

```
def f(n):
    assert 0<n<7, "numbers should be between 1 and 6"
    return n-1 if n!=1 else 6, n+1 if n!=6 else 1
f(1)
#result (6, 2)
```

Comment: List of days not required, that was just for understanding the total no.s

Comment: Then please verify if my code fulfill your requirements.

Comment: It's ok. In any case, so far you have 3 answers. Look what works best for you, or maybe combine the answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `trick` you mentioned is famous as circular linked list. Please correct me if I'm wrong about it.

```
day_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
def get_prev_next(elem):
    if elem not in day_list:
       return False     # element not found
    index = day_list.index(elem)
    return day_list[i - 1], l[(i + 1) % len(day_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the *previous*, you can take advantage of the fact that when indexing a list, negative indexes mean "*negative starting on the last element*". It helps me thinking about the `[-1]` as "overflowing", which means going to the first element (index `0`) and start counting from the last element.

For the *next*, you can use the [modulo (%)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator, to make sure you keep your indexes between `0` and `len(days_list)`. This is only critical in the case the index of the number you want to calculate the next is the last element of the list (index `5`, value `6` in the `day_list`). Just adding `+1` to the index `5` would put you in `6`, which is not a valid **`index`**. But then you get the module of `6 % 6` and "becomes" `0`.

```
day_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


def find(thing):
    position = day_list.index(thing)
    prev_pos = day_list[position - 1]
    next_pos = day_list[(position + 1) % len(day_list)]
    return prev_pos, next_pos


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1, 7):
        print("prev_next %s: %s" % (i, find(i)))
```

Outputs:

```
prev_next 1: (6, 2)
prev_next 2: (1, 3)
prev_next 3: (2, 4)
prev_next 4: (3, 5)
prev_next 5: (4, 6)
prev_next 6: (5, 1)
```